# Postgres and math on columns during insert or update

Tags: sql, postgresql

When inserting or updating data I would like to be able to perform some math on two columns and have that entered as a value for a third column.

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."subscriptions" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('subscriptions_id_seq'::regclass),
    "item" varchar,
    "amount" float4,
    "yearly_recurrance" int2,
    "annual_cost" float4,
    "rank" int2,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."subscriptions" ("item", "amount", "yearly_recurrance", "rank") VALUES ('test', '19', '7', '0');
```

I have created a function and trigger that in my mind should take the amount and multiply it by the yearly_recurrance and enter the result in the annual_cost field.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calc_cost()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
NEW.annual_cost = NEW.amount * NEW.yearly_recurrance;
RETURN NEW;
END;

$function$
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER calc_cost BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON subscriptions
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_cost();
```

It is not working out how I expect.   Instead the values from the insert statement are put where they belong, but it is as though the function doesn't run.   Not getting any errors that I can see.

I should mention that I believe the trigger is working and calling the function.  If I put garbage in the function I get errors.    I think the problem is in the function.  Given this is my first function however, I am not sure how to work with uncommitted data.  Perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: This should work just as you expect. Perhaps you could come up with a complete reproducible test case, If you are using v12 or above, consider using a generated column.

Comment: Using a generated column is the better solution. But that does not answer why your trigger solution does not work. The reason for that is you have a STATEMENT level trigger. That trigger fires *once* before any actual data is processed. The new data values at that point are null. You trigger would work by changing "for each statement" to "for each row". See [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generated column instead:

```
alter table subscriptions
    add annual_cost float4 generated always as (amount * yearly_recurrance) stored;
```

No trigger overhead and it is always accurate.

Note:  I don't recommend floats for monetary amounts; rounding errors can be problematic.  Use `numeric`.

Comment: I like this suggestion but I get the following error when altering the table:  ```Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2: ...st numeric generated always as (amount * yearly_recurrance);
```

Comment: I dropped the column and retreated it.    works beautifully.   thank you

Comment: Postgres only supports `stored` generated columns, not "virtual" ones that are evaluated during select

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Of course.  That hasn't changed, yet.  I'm waiting.